# how to solve (settingWithCopyWarning: A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.)?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

> This my code to create a new column with a calculation in a data frame

```
df1['Cases/Tests/1M pop']= (df1['Tot Cases/1M pop']/ df1['Tests/ 1M pop'])*100
```

> and I got this error message in the output

```
settingWithCopyWarning:
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead
See the caveats in the documentation: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy
 df1['Cases/Tests/1M pop']= (df1['Tot Cases/1M pop']/ df1['Tests/ 1M pop'])*100
```

Comment: Add `.copy()` when creating df1.

Comment: yes it works now. Thank you @ScottBoston !!

Comment: yes, it works @TrentonMcKinney